# How to get the date of previous month matching specified day ? [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I get the date of previous month matching specified day ? in Swift

if I have  this function `getPreviousMonthDate(matchingDay day: Int) -> Date`

***Examples:***
following (dd/mm/yyyy)

- If Today is `25/07/2022` and I call `getPreviousMonthDate(matchingDay: 27)`
  : return value would be `27/06/2022` .
- If Today is `18/04/2022` and I call `getPreviousMonthDate(matchingDay: 14)`
  : return value would be `14/03/2022` .
- If Today is `15/01/2022` and I call `getPreviousMonthDate(matchingDay: 16)`
  : return value would be `16/12/2021` .

and so on...

Comment: Please use the edited answer which accounts for the first month of the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use date components as following:

```
func getPreviousMonthDate(matchingDay day: Int) -> Date {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let comps = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
    var comps2 = DateComponents()
    comps2.year = comps.year
    comps2.month = comps.month! - 1
    comps2.day = day
    return calendar.date(from: comps2)!
}
```

I force-unwrapped the date to match your function declaration, I suggest that you deal with the optional dates properly though.

Comment: Your if condition here is pointless. if month is equal to zero it automatically results in December of the previous year. Btw no need to create two date components objects.